# Does cross-platform C++ require building separately on every single platform?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, cross-platform, interop

My question actually has two variants, but for some context, I have a C++ *.DLL that I use with [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) using [P/Invoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services). It's built on Windows 10 with [MSBuild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) (platform toolset: ClangCL).

And now for my questions,

1. Does the size of a particular type stay constant **after** the DLL has been built? Or does it need to be rebuilt again on the target platform (say, Linux or Mac)?

My code looks a bit like this:

```
typedef wchar_t wchar;
static_assert(sizeof(wchar) == 2, "WideChar size-test failed.");
```

After I have recompiled the source on Windows, if I build the Unity project for the Android platform, will the size of *wchar* remain the same on there as well? Or am I in for a nasty surprise when my string-handling code just stops working?

2. Are some of the other language features maintained after the DLL is built, or do I need to change my workflow to account for something else?

In particular, let's look at something super-basic, like *extern* methods.

```
#define CALLING_CONVENTION __stdcall

#if _WIN32
#define DLLEXPORT(type) extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) type CALLING_CONVENTION
#else
#define DLLEXPORT(type) extern "C" type CALLING_CONVENTION
#endif

DLLEXPORT(void) DoSomething(const wchar* ManagedString);
// expands to
// extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall DoSomething(const wchar* ManagedString)
// on Windows
```

And for managed,

```
[DllImport("DllName", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern void DoSomething([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string input);
```

Will this maintain interoperability for other platforms as well? Or do I need to go out of my way to build the C++ DLL on Linux and then use *that* for an Android platform?

Comment: *"build the C++ DLL on Linux"* -- cannot be done. Linux uses `.so` (shared object) files instead of the Windows-specific DLL format. You might be able to build a shared library on Linux from your C++ source, but not a DLL. Did you mean "shared library" instead of "DLL" or is this getting at the reason for your question?

Comment: @JaMiT in that case, my question is still the same. Do I need to rebuild the project into an *.so to use it for a Unity project when I deploy on Android?

Comment: @JaMiT -- there's no technical reason that a compiler running on Linux couldn't create a DLL. You couldn't **use** the DLL on Linux, because Linux traffics in Linux-specific .so format.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, that's technically true, but that's not really what the OP was talking about. Cross-compiling a Windows DLL on Linux would use the Windows ABI, the same as if it was compiled on Windows. The OP was thinking that switching to Linux would change the ABI (even if the OP didn't know the term "ABI"). I was going to mention that a DLL could not be used by Android, but [WineHQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/Download) might disagree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each platform usually has a different [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). For example, `long` on Windows is 32-bit (from memory), but `long` on Linux is 64-bit. In your example, `wchar_t` on Windows is 16-bit, but on Linux it is 32-bit. The way that C++ names are mangled is also platform-specific.

Both Windows and Linux have different syscalls (standard library functions like [malloc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) usually end up calling platform-specific syscalls). But not only that; the way that each platform stores and loads executable code (and how it dynamically links to other executable code) is also different, and without some sort of translator in between (such as [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/)), it's typically not possible to run executable code that was compiled for a different platform.

So in general, you will need to compile your code for each platform you intend to support. See also [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1445698/dlls-work-on-windows-but-not-on-android.html) in the Unity forums.

Comment: Could you maybe guide me to some way I can build a *.so/*.dylib file using MSBuild on a Windows PC?

Comment: [Here's some MS documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/create-a-new-linux-project?view=msvc-160) on how to use Visual Studio to target Linux, and [here's](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cross-platform/install-visual-cpp-for-cross-platform-mobile-development?view=msvc-160) a more general topic in the documentation that also shows you can target Android and iOS. I have no experience in this area however. Note that according to this documentation, you are required to have an Apple Developer account and a Mac running macOS and Xcode (because of licensing requirements)